# What is faster in a for loop comparison?

Tags: c, performance

My guess would be that in c89 Version 1 is faster because `sizeof` is a compile time operator, so we will be comparing with a constant. But in c99 we can take `sizeof` a VLA, so `sizeof` is a run time operator.
So which one is faster in c99? 
And which one is faster in c89?

One define and array for both of them:

```
#define NUM_ROWS(x) (int) (sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))

int x[5] = { 0 };
```

Version 1:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS(x); i++) { 
    // code
}
```

Version 2:

```
const int length = NUM_ROWS(x);
int i;
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) { 
    // code
}
```

Comment: Which of these did you profile? None, one of them, or both?

Comment: This question has no much sense in a real world IMO. I am pretty sure that most compilers are smart enough to figure out whether `sizeof` changes it's value or not during loop execution and will optimize it. That said, it probably doesn't have to, so it's dependent on the compiler and optimizations.

Comment: @Jongware Both of them. But I could not do it properly to be honest, its not such an easy task to perform a profile without bias. (And I never needed to use profiling tools before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only true answer to what is faster is: measure.

That said, in version 1 you evaluate and end condition at each iteration of your loop, and in version 2 you only evaluate it once.

Even if sizeof is a constant if you compiler can put the constant value directly in a register for comparison in version 1, it could probably do the same in version 2.

So version2 is in theory either faster or at worst the same speed than version1 (most likely for a constant expression).

Comment: "*always faster and at worst the same speed*" <- So always faster, or not? Always is always.

Comment: @luk32 okay, i've used some more pedantic words ;)

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking but I value logic, maybe too high =). Also my bet is that 99,9% of optimization mechanisms will figure out it's a loop invariant and treat it as a constant.

Comment: I don't like this answer because it's not pragmatic, and might give the false illusion that there's some chance to do micro-optimization trickery...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath When it comes down to optimisation it all depends on your plateforme, i'm not sure i can pragmatically cover all of them in an answer, but if you got any edit suggestion my ears are all open :)

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` is *only* evaluated at run-time if a VLA is part of the expression.

Since that's not the case, it'll be just a compile time constant, and you will get the same performance.